# Socket.io authentication with access-token or refresh-token?

Tags: node.js, http, websocket, tcp, socket.io

I am building web app with React.js and Socket.io, the login system uses Http-request to the express server which provide me a refresh token stored in cookies with httpOnly option, and access-token attached to response body with some other credentials, the server validate every http request by verifying the access-token reside in the authorization headers, and generate new one in cause of expiration.

The app contain a social media and chat sections as well, so i have built a socket implementation in the server as well, but the problem is currently i am using a middle-ware to validate every new socket connection with the server by verifying the refresh token which is assigned to the cookies, and i am not sure about the downsides of this practice, the only thing i am sure about is that when the user refresh-token expires, the app won't kick him back to login if he remained using sockets and didn't triggered any http-request, simply because the socket authentication middle-ware execute only on the on-connect event.

1. should I authenticate sockets using access-tokens as well?
2. should I authenticate every incoming events instead?
3. should i start a new
   socket connection every time access-token expires or there is
   another solution?
4. updating the socket handshake auth cause the
   socket to disconnect as far as i know, should I use extraHeaders
   instead or there is better solution?

Comment: What do you mean "updating the socket handshake auth cause the socket to disconnect as far as i know" ?  The auth is done during 101 negotiation, I use https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#sending-credentials without any problem.

Comment: @Qiulang , I think you didn't understand my use case, or me missing something, " the socket.handshake.headers object contains the headers that were sent during the Socket.IO handshake", as i said, my access token expires quickly, and the express server generate new one and send it to front-end, front end is the responsible for setting it to the socket instance. will this scenario work as you mentioned? i am beginner and not married to this authentication scenario, if you can propose me better one, it would be great and very appreciated.